# WIll overlaying the screen with a dark UIView save battery power?

Tags: ios, battery, batterylevel

Would a full screen black overlay UIView with a 0.8 alpha value reduce battery drain the same as setting the device system brightness to a low value?

I would prefer to use my own UIView overlay so I can animate it smoothly dimming the screen rather than messing with the users device settings.

Thanks for any help.

Geoff
iOS 6, Universal app

Comment: yes, it would the same way using blackle.com would save energy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so; the backlight is on regardless of what is on the screen, and this is what costs the energy. Luckily there is the energy diagnostics tool in instruments which may help you prove it one way or the other.